# Excel Function (or VBA) to check the same value in cells

Tags: vba, excel

If I have like

In first table in sheet1 looks like this

```
A1   B1
aaa- yes
aaa- no
aaa- no
aaa- no
aaa- no
aaa- yes
aaa- no
bbb- no
bbb- no
bbb- no
bbb- no
bbb- no
bbb- no
ccc- no
ccc- no
ccc- yes
```

and the next Answer sheet2 is like

```
A1   B1
aaa- Yes
bbb- No
ccc- yes
```

Can I ask you for function or (VBA Code) that is checking that

if any same name on sheet1 is "yes" the answer in sheet2 is "yes"
esle if it's all no then on sheet2 is "No"

If that sounded confusing please ask.

Comment: `1.` Have you tried anything? `2.` What if you have a `yes` in front of `bbb`? `3.` What if you have `no` in front of `aaa`? `4.` Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: i try use my old match+index formula it show #value! in some cell it should show not showing that so i change my method.

bbb- is in column A and Yes,No is in Column B  

i use 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it can be addressed with a formula. The following formula assumes that the Sheet 1 data is in the range A1:B16.

```
    =IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1&"yes",Sheet1!$A$1:$A$16&Sheet1!$B$1:$B$16,0)),"no","yes")
```

This would be the formula for the first entry in Sheet 2, which I assume is in cell A1.

Note that this is an array formula, so it needs to be entered with the Control-Shift-Enter key combination.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2007 or later versions you can use COUNTIFS like this:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,A1,Sheet1!B:B,"yes"),"Yes","No")`